# Developing an application for communication between computers in a network

Tags: java, rmi

I need to develop a software application for a computers in a network in the following scenario:
Computers in a network are monitored by another master computer running a controller program. The controller is a software appln which performs network discovery, gets data from the discovered computers and performs a set of operations on the discovered computers.

I have made progress until this level:
1. Program for network discovery. o/p is IPs of all the active machines on n/w.
2. Basic program implementing RMI(rejected sockets as the program might have diff implementations)

My doubts:
1.Assuming that I need to send the instructions of operation to be executed on client machines with diff IPs, how do I do it with RMI? How do I connect to other clients,in the first place using RMI?
2.After connecting, how do I transmit instructions to and fro the controller?

Please help me out!

Comment: @Jim Garrison- Well, I've got to do it this way as its project which replicates the popular Virtual machine manager's operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try reading the JNDI tutorial. It covers aspects of discovering other computers and communicating them at a level that may be useful to your project. The tutorial is located here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/trailmap.html